# Laravel 8 Jetstream Undefined Header

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-jetstream

I am trying to learn Jetstream.  I have a dashboard template that works for most things but when I try to do the following but remove  I get undefined variable header.  How can I remove the header component?

```
@extends('admin.admin_master')
@section('admin')

<x-app-layout>
    <x-slot name="header">
        <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">
            {{ __('Profile') }}
        </h2>
    </x-slot>

    <div>
        <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto py-10 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
            @livewire('profile.update-profile-information-form')

            @if (Laravel\Fortify\Features::enabled(Laravel\Fortify\Features::updatePasswords()))
                <x-jet-section-border />
            
                <div class="mt-10 sm:mt-0">
                    @livewire('profile.update-password-form')
                </div>
            @endif

            @if (Laravel\Fortify\Features::canManageTwoFactorAuthentication())
                <x-jet-section-border />

                <div class="mt-10 sm:mt-0">
                    @livewire('profile.two-factor-authentication-form')
                </div>
            @endif

            <x-jet-section-border />

            <div class="mt-10 sm:mt-0">
                @livewire('profile.logout-other-browser-sessions-form')
            </div>

            <x-jet-section-border />

            <div class="mt-10 sm:mt-0">
                @livewire('profile.delete-user-form')
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</x-app-layout>
@endsection
```